# Saving image with openCv and c

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to load an image, then convert it to a gray scale and then to save it. I am using C and not C++ so I cannot use in Mat like all the other posts her (yes I read them all so do not Bother me).

I saw that I should use in the function `imwrite` that get 2 parameters: the name and the IplImage.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core_c.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>

int main(void)
{
    IplImage* im_gray = cvLoadImage("pic.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    imwrite("outputGray.jpg", im_gray);
}
```

I get this error

```
Error 1 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`imwrite` is the `C++` version, you must use [`cvSaveImage`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvloadimage#int%20cvSaveImage(const%20char*%20filename,%20const%20CvArr*%20image,%20const%20int*%20params)) which has a signature like this:

```
int cvSaveImage(const char* filename, const CvArr* image, const int* params=0 )
```

first parameter is the filename, second one is the image and thrd one is the options.

Your code will be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <opencv2\core\core_c.h>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui_c.h>

int main(void)
{
    IplImage* im_gray = cvLoadImage("pic.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cvSaveImage("outputGray.jpg", im_gray);
}
```

Comment: @mr.knowall there is only 2 arguments needed, the third one is optional